# String Replacing using Sed or Awk

Tags: regex, shell, sed, regex-lookarounds, awk

Cat vols.txt (This list can fluctuate depending on the vols a system might have)

```
$Vol01
$Vol02
$Vol03
$Vol04
$Vol04
$Vol05
$Vol06
$Vol07
$Vol08
```

if I do:

```
cat datavols.log | sed -n 's/^\$.*/vanish \\&\.acd\*\.\* -db ! \&/gp' >> workfile.txt
```

I get:

```
cat workfile.txt

vanish $Vol01.acd*.* -db ! &
vanish $Vol02.acd*.* -db ! &
vanish $Vol03.acd*.* -db ! &
vanish $Vol04.acd*.* -db ! &
vanish $Vol05.acd*.* -db ! &
vanish $Vol06.acd*.* -db ! &
vanish $Vol07.acd*.* -db ! &
vanish $Vol08.acd*.* -db ! &
```

I have got 4 CPUs and I want to distribute the work between them and the output should be something like:

```
cat workfile.txt

Run –cpu=0 vanish $Vol01.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=1 vanish $Vol02.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=2 vanish $Vol03.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=3 vanish $Vol04.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=0 vanish $Vol05.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=1 vanish $Vol06.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=2 vanish $Vol07.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=3 vanish $Vol08.acd*.* -db ! &
```

Kindly help me getting this. I am not sure how to have a variable iterate between 0-3 inside SED. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{i=0}{print "Run –cpu="i " vanish "$1".acd*.* -db ! &"; i=(i+1)%4}' inputfile
```

will produce the output as

```
 Run –cpu=0 vanish $Vol01.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=1 vanish $Vol02.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=2 vanish $Vol03.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=3 vanish $Vol04.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=0 vanish $Vol05.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=1 vanish $Vol06.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=2 vanish $Vol07.acd*.* -db ! &
Run –cpu=3 vanish $Vol08.acd*.* -db ! &
```

Comment: Thanks .. This was short and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FNR`, the current line number of the file, in `awk`:

```
awk '{print "Run -cpu=" (FNR-1)%4 " vanish " $0 ".acd*.* -db | &"}' vols.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your time. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this simple `bash script` .

```
Total_Cpu=4
Count=0
while read line ; do
   if [ $Count  -eq  4 ] ;then
      Count=0
   fi
    echo $line | sed "s/^\$.*/Run –cpu=$Count vanish \&.acd*.* -db ! \&/g" >> Output_file
    Count=`expr $Count + 1`         
done < Input_File
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '1{x;s/^/0123/;x};G;s/(.*)\n(.)(.*)/Run -cpu=\2 vanish \1.acd*.* -db ! \&\n\3\2/;P;s/.*\n//;h file
```

Create a line with the sequence of the cpu's you want and store it in the hold space (HS).

Append the HS to the current line  and using the substitute command insert the cpu number and the required strings prepping the cpu order for the next line.

Print the string then replace the amended cpu order in the HS.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '1 {
   x;s/^/Run –cpu=3 vanish :-D.acd*.* -db ! \&/;x
   }
x;y/0123/1230/;G;s/\(.*sh \)[^.]\{1,\}\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/;h' YourFile
```

a bit like potong bt using the last line as previous reference only changing the $vol content and cpu value